# How to setup default bundle split folder in android

Tags: android, textures, game-engine

I am trying to setup texture split for my application following this [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/texture-compression#supported-suffixes) from official documentation. I want to have ASTC as my primary compression and png as my fallback.

The split apks are generated properly as expected and I am able to extract and install the apks properly in the devices where ASTC is supported. However, in the devices where it is not supported I am getting this error and default assets are not being packed for this.
Am I missing something in the setup due to which default is not getting used properly? Is there a way to debug this?

I am unable to find any relevant documentation around this. You help is highly appreciated.

build.gradle

```
bundle {
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }

        density {
            enableSplit = false
        }

        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }

        texture {
            enableSplit true
        }
    }
```

folder structure:

app/assets/textures (For default png assets)
app/assets/textures#tcf_astc

I am building the apk with android studio Build -> Build Bundle(s)/ APK (s) -> Build Bundle(s)

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=app/build/outputs/bundle/testAppDebug/test-app-debug.aab --output=/Users/test/apks/testapp.apks

bundletool extract-apks --apks=/Users/test/apks/testapp.apks --device-spec=/Users/test/apks/redmigo.json --output-dir /Users/test/apks/outputApk

or 

bundletool install-apks --apks=/Users/test/apks/testapp.apks
```

zipinfo test.apks

```
-rw-rw-rw-  0.0 unx      609 b- stor 81-Jan-01 01:01 toc.pb
-rw-rw-rw-  0.0 unx 34632621 b- stor 81-Jan-01 01:01 splits/base-armeabi_v7a.apk
-rw-rw-rw-  0.0 unx 90633133 b- stor 81-Jan-01 01:01 splits/base-armeabi_v7a_2.apk
-rw-rw-rw-  0.0 unx     8555 b- stor 81-Jan-01 01:01 splits/base-astc.apk
-rw-rw-rw-  0.0 unx 94741185 b- stor 81-Jan-01 01:01 splits/base-master.apk
-rw-rw-rw-  0.0 unx 94741185 b- stor 81-Jan-01 01:01 splits/base-master_2.apk
-rw-rw-rw-  0.0 unx   131434 b- stor 81-Jan-01 01:01 splits/base-other_tcf.apk
```

Error:

```
[BT:1.15.6] Error: The app doesn't support texture compression formats of the device. Device formats: [ATC, ETC1_RGB8, ETC2], app formats: [ASTC].
com.android.tools.build.bundletool.model.exceptions.IncompatibleDeviceException: The app doesn't support texture compression formats of the device. Device formats: [ATC, ETC1_RGB8, ETC2], app formats: [ASTC].
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.model.exceptions.UserExceptionBuilder.build(UserExceptionBuilder.java:58)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.TextureCompressionFormatMatcher.checkDeviceCompatibleInternal(TextureCompressionFormatMatcher.java:154)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.TextureCompressionFormatMatcher.checkDeviceCompatibleInternal(TextureCompressionFormatMatcher.java:44)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.TargetingDimensionMatcher.checkDeviceCompatible(TargetingDimensionMatcher.java:121)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.ApkMatcher.checkCompatibleWithApkTargetingHelper(ApkMatcher.java:341)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.ApkMatcher.lambda$checkCompatibleWithApkTargeting$12(ApkMatcher.java:336)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:422)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.ApkMatcher.checkCompatibleWithApkTargeting(ApkMatcher.java:336)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.ApkMatcher.lambda$getMatchingApksFromModule$3(ApkMatcher.java:178)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$15$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:540)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1708)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.ApkMatcher.getMatchingApksFromModule(ApkMatcher.java:180)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.ApkMatcher.lambda$getMatchingApksFromVariant$2(ApkMatcher.java:170)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:273)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1708)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.ApkMatcher.getMatchingApksFromVariant(ApkMatcher.java:171)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.ApkMatcher.getMatchingApks(ApkMatcher.java:148)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.commands.ExtractApksCommand.execute(ExtractApksCommand.java:217)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.commands.ExtractApksCommand.execute(ExtractApksCommand.java:198)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.BundleToolMain.main(BundleToolMain.java:107)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.BundleToolMain.main(BundleToolMain.java:55)
```